# DLL : export as a C/C++ function?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dllexport

I generated a DLL in Visual from a C++ code. Dependency Walker sees 3 functions exported as C functions.

I made an SCons project to do the generate the DLL, and 2 of the 3 functions are not seen as C functions.

What makes a function seen as a or C++ function, without modifying the code ? It must be in the compilation/linking options, but I didn't find any relevant thing.

The function are prefixed by a macro : AM_LIB_EXPORT

In the .h, I have :

```
#ifdef _WIN32
#define AM_LIB_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define AM_LIB_EXPORT
#endif // _WIN32
```

Thanks.

Comment: take a look at (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions)

Comment: Are you sure that _WIN32 is defined when compiling using scons ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What makes a function seen as a or C++ function, without modifying the code ?

A function compiled by a C++ compiler is automatically a 'C++-function' and name-mangling occurs to resolve C++ features such as namespaces and overloading. 
In order to get 'C' export names, one must use the aforementioned `extern "C"` qualifier in the function declaration. Alternatively a huge `extern "C" { .. }` block around the header containing the prototypes.

If this does not solve your issue, its maybe related to dllimport/dllexport. If you `#define AM_LIB_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)` in your DLL build, you'll typically also need to make it `dllimport` for apps linking against your DLL in order for the linker to know where to fetch the symbols from.

Answer (score 3):

Is this a name mangling issue? If you don't use `extern "C"` around your function declarations, they will get name-mangled.

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason :

The export was also added as additionnal command line option (/EXPORT). In this case, it is exported as a C function. I don't understand why...

I removed this additionnal command line switch.

Thank you all.

I still don't know how to mark a thread as "resolved" ?