# Use of a #define Macro while defining a class in C++

Tags: c++

```
#define EXPORT_SPEC 

class EXPORT_SPEC CBoard {
.......
}
```

What is the use or purpose of EXPORT_SPEC in the above class definition.

how this class definition is different from normal class definition.

Ur help is highly appreciated.

Comment: That depends on the definition of the EXPORT_SPEC macro.

Comment: Find the definition of macro, i have included it in the above question too. #define EXPORT_SPEC

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DLL : export as a C/C++ function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2094427/dll-export-as-a-c-c-function)

Comment: @el.pescado: Not an exact duplicate, although the underlying explanation may be the same, the question is quite different.

Answer (score 0):

**None** is the answer to your question.  The macro has no value so it will be "removed" by the pre-processor.  As el.pescado  said, macros like this are used to build libraries (as opposed to stand-alone apps).

Answer (score 0):

The point of the #define use is to specify a non-changing value. In the case you are mentioning, you would be able to set the name of a class according to some preference set in that #define call. E.g.

```
#define CLASS_NAME "Employee"

class CLASS_NAME something {
...
}
```

In this case, you can change the class / object name by the #define call. I don't know if there is too much use in that, or at least not too much that I can think of.

This question was also addressed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20979584/how-to-use-macro-define-to-change-class-name).